# pypiserver - Package description doesn't appear in pip search

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, pypiserver

I am struggling to find information about how / where to fill a summary for a PyPI package that can be seen next to the package name when typing `pip search <my_package>`.

We run a private PyPI server with the **pypiserver** library and would like all our packages to have this short description, similarly to any package on *pypi.org*.

In my package's `setup.py` I filled `description` and `long_description` but it still doesn't show us any summary when using `pip search`.

When I do `pip install <my_package>` and look inside the downloaded egg, I see the `PKG_INFO` file with `summary` field filled appropriately.

Comment: I have the same issue: what is the "description" for in setup.py if not to fill that field?

Comment: Never got an answer for that one ...

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered, there is no summary provided.
In pypiserver/_app.py:218 written:

```
            # We do not presently have any description/summary, returning
            # version instead
```